# Is it possible to use iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached with Cognito Identity policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

The documentation of `AttachThingPrincipal` states that:

> You can use the AttachThingPrincipal API to attach certificates and **authenticated Amazon Cognito identities** to a Thing.

However, when I try to use `iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached` in an IAM policy, like so:

```json
"Condition": {
    "Bool": {
        "iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached": "true"
    }
}
```

I get the error "invalid condition key format". This remains the case when I play with the key value, like using ${}, and removing the quotes.

Whenever I see examples of the use of `iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached`, it's always in the context of an IoT policy, but that pertains to the Thing's policy, while I'm trying to configure the Cognito Identity permissions to access the device shadow. If Cognito identities are supposedly supported by `AttachThingPrincipal`, then how do I address their attached status in the IAM role policy that's associated with the identity?